# How to adjust subplot size in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, seaborn

```
%matplotlib inline
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4)
m = 0
l = 0
for i in k: 
    if l == 4 and m==0:
        m+=1
        l = 0
    data1[i].plot(kind = 'box', ax=axes[m,l], figsize = (12,5))
    l+=1
```

This outputs subplots as desired.

[image: Pandas Boxplots]

But when trying to achieve it through seaborn, subplots are stacked close to each other, how do I change size of each subplot?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4)
m = 0
l = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
for i in k: 
    if l == 4 and m==0:
        m+=1
        l = 0
    sns.boxplot(x= data1[i],  orient='v' , ax=axes[m,l])
    l+=1
```

[image: Seaborn Boxplots]

Comment: My up-vote represents my agreement that that looks messed up, I've no idea how to fix it, and I want to see if someone else can.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your call to `plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))` is creating a new empty figure different from your already declared `fig` from the first step. Set the `figsize` in your call to `plt.subplots`. It defaults to (6,4) in your plot since you did not set it. You already created your figure and assigned to variable `fig`. If you wanted to act on that figure you should have done `fig.set_size_inches(12, 5)` instead to change the size.

You can then simply call `fig.tight_layout()` to get the plot fitted nicely.

Also, there is a much easier way to iterate through axes by using `flatten` on your array of `axes` objects. I am also using data directly from seaborn itself.

```
# I first grab some data from seaborn and make an extra column so that there
# are exactly 8 columns for our 8 axes
data = sns.load_dataset('car_crashes')
data = data.drop('abbrev', axis=1)
data['total2'] = data['total'] * 2

# Set figsize here
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(12,5))

# if you didn't set the figsize above you can do the following
# fig.set_size_inches(12, 5)

# flatten axes for easy iterating
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    sns.boxplot(x= data.iloc[:, i],  orient='v' , ax=ax)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Without the `tight_layout` the plots are slightly smashed together. See below.

[image]

Comment: How do you do a 2*2 subplotting so you have two boxplots per axs?